# Compiling Kernel Fails with certificate error

Tags: kernel, compiling

I'm trying to build the kernel from here: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/kvalo/ath.git/

and it fails with certificate error.  I have run sudo make menuconfig, and then have edited the resulting .config file with nano to comment out "CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS".  It still fails with certificate error.  The build process does ask questions about keys, and I think this is where the .config file is getting updated and resulting in the failure.  If I edit the .config file afterwards "CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS" is no longer commented out.  Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

EDIT: Further details:

I am following this guide: https://tutorialforlinux.com/2021/03/11/how-to-install-kernel-5-12-from-source-on-ubuntu-21-04/3/ and I am using 21.04.  The only difference is that I am downloading the kernel source from the git linked above.  There are some pre-requisites that the guide omits (flex, bison, dwarves), but I know that and install those before hand.  I get to the command where you actually build the kernel packages, and it asks a lot of questions, presumably because the ubuntu kernel config I copied previously doesn't have config values for the new kernel.  One of the questions is about trusted keys, and it restores the "CONFIG_TRUSTED_SYSTEM_KEYS" config switch that I previously commented out per the guide.  The build then tries to locate keys which aren't there and it fails.  Commenting out "CONFIG_TRUSTED_SYSTEM_KEYS" has worked in the past.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to finally get this to work by instead of commenting out the variable, setting it to an empty string.  For example, CONFIG_TRUSTED_SYSTEM_KEYS="" is what worked for me.